# How did Jane die?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In Breaking Bad, season 2, ep 12 ~ ep 13, Jesse's girl friend / landlord Jane died.

She started vomiting during sleep, and died shortly after.

I would imagine vomiting violently like she was would have waken herself up and it would not be so hard to stand up from her bed and saved herself from choking.

Or she die because of other reasons?

I heard of people suffocated themselves with their own vomit due to being deeply drunk, but not being in sleep.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How did Jane start suffocating after smoking heroin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/how-did-jane-start-suffocating-after-smoking-heroin)